# How to avoid an activity to reload every time i get into it?

Tags: java, android

Hello I have an activity which shows some listviews, and I want them not to reload/refresh every time I get into it, as it is programmed to show different items every time.
But I want it not to refresh until a button which is in another activity is pushed.

I've not tried anything yet as I don't know what to start with.

Here I leave you the code of the java.class:

```
public class Comida extends AppCompatActivity implements Adaptador2.OnRecipeListener {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    List<Entidad2> listItems;
    Adaptador2 adaptor;
    private Entidad2 entidad1,entidad2,entidad3;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String myValue = savedInstanceState.getString("key");
        }

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comida);

        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.lv_1);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        entidad1 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.calabacines_3, "Solomillo a la plancha", " 10 min.", 4, 20);
        entidad2 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.patatas_deluxe_especiadas_70523_300_150, "Entrecot", " 15 min.", 2, 50);
        entidad3 = new Entidad2(R.drawable.tomate, "Hamburguesa", " 2 min.", 5, 100);


        listItems.add(entidad1);
        listItems.add(entidad2);
        listItems.add(entidad3);

        adaptor = new Adaptador2(listItems, this);
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(adaptor);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pickEntidad();
    }

    @Override
    public void OnRecipe(int priority) {

        if (priority == 20) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Solomillo.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 50) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Entrecot.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
        if (priority == 100) {
            Intent in = new Intent(this, Hamburguesa.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }

    private void pickEntidad(){
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(101);

        int priority1 = entidad1.getPriority();
        int priority2 = entidad2.getPriority();
        int priority3 = entidad3.getPriority();


        listItems.clear();
        if(random < priority1){

            listItems.add(entidad1);

        }else if(random < priority2){

            listItems.add(entidad2);

        }else if (random <= priority3){

            listItems.add(entidad3);

        }
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And then here there is the java.class of the other activity(the one which contains the button that has to refresh the other activity):

- The button which I want to use to refresh the activity is the boton_prueba.

```
public class Menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button boton_start;
    Button boton_refresh;
    Button boton_prueba;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        boton_start=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_platos);
        boton_refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_cambiarmenu);
        boton_prueba=(Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_menu);

        boton_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(Menu.this,Dishes.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        boton_prueba.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent in = new Intent(Menu.this,Comida.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });

        boton_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               //What to do?

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Please if anyone has any idea of how to do it help me and in case you need more code or information just tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: So basically From menu activity, when the user has click boton_refresh button then you want to execute  pickEntidad() method.

and when you go to Comida activity, you want updated list

Comment: Yes I that is it, but how do I do it, in the activity menu what do I have to write? A setOnclickListener? @KishanMaurya

Answer (score 0):

If I really understand you then you want to execute `pickEntidad()` method when pressing in refresh button and go to this activity so you can do that using send any number or data with the intent like:

```
 Intent in = new Intent(currentActivity.this,targetActivity.class);
            in.putExtra("number",2);
            startActivity(in);
```

and in target activity use somthing like this:

```
 if(getIntent().getIntExtra("number",-1) ==2)
    {
        // what do you want to do...
    }
```

Comment: No I don't want to press the refresh button, what I want is that when i get into the activity and all the information refreshes automatically, avoid it to happen. And then make all the activity refresh by pressing a button on another activity. Any idea of how to do it please? @Ahmed Alaa Hussein

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean you want the whole activity to refresh by pressing the button or you want just to refresh the listview using  pickEntidad() method. Can you please lend me some information to try to help you please?

Comment: I only want to refresh the listview using pickEntidad().

Comment: the you can use my code to make what you do put the intent in the refresh button and use this if condition to call pickEntidad() method